# iOS Localization (setting it in the app)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, localization

in my application I must have two languages, but the problem is that they should be switched by pressing a button in the application (on the first screen, or screen settings). As I understand, all the methods of `localization` (`Localizing` the `Storyboard`, `Localizing Dynamic Strings`) based on the language settings of the iPhone. The only option that comes to my mind - do it by the record in `NSUserDefault` about language preference, and in `ViewDidLoad` methods of all `ViewControllers` check the record about language and in accordance with it set strings, picture and so on. Can it be done on a more clever way?

Comment: u got or not ? if u stuck let us know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

If de is the new language selected by the user. Also assure that you are reinitiating the current view.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"de", nil] 
                                      forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

See the below link and source code

http://learning-ios.blogspot.com/2011/04/advance-localization-in-ios-apps.html

and here is the code of one sample app https://github.com/object2dot0/Advance-Localization-in-ios-apps

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

this tutorial & sample app helpful you more

[localization-tutorial-for-ios](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios)

[ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/)

Answer (score 0):

Ya The way you are following for Localization is not up to Mark.

Please Follow this beautiful tutorial  http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually mange the currently selected language into user default and load the bundle folder according to selected language key like, i have done this and worked like charm

```
if ([currentLanguage isEqualToString:@"fr"]) {  // If French.
        languageBundle = nil;
        NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fr" ofType:@"lproj"];
        languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
}
```